# Replacing all existing data in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to replace all data in a table with a specified field (for example user_id=some_number). I've tried `DELETE` followed by `INSERT`, but that seems to do some problems and am looking for a better solution to do that. In addition, most of the rows are still the same, so it this approach is probably not too efficient. I've ran into `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY / REPLACE` but those will keep the some of the old data and not delete it, if I understand it correctly. I've thought about doing a `SELECT` and comparing the values in `PHP` but thought mysql might have implemented this for me. Is there an option to do that with a query?

UPDATE: 
To be clearer, Lets say I have inside table my_table these values:

```
col1 col2 col3  
v1   v2   v3   
v1   v4   v5  
v1   v6   v7
v2   v8   v9
```

I would like to up replace all col1=v1 rows with this data:

```
col1 col2  col3  
v1   v10   v11   
v1   v4    v5
```

So I should end up deleting one row, keeping one the same, and updating another.
So the table will look like this at the end of the operation:

```
col1 col2  col3  
v1   v10   v11   
v1   v4    v5 
v2   v8   v9
```

Did this clear things up?

Comment: Have you tried update?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear (or I'm understanding update wrong). Each new row, will receive different values, and I'm not updating all the rows with the same value.

Comment: What do you mean by "but that seems to do some problems"? What problems specifically? Also, it's a little unclear on exactly what your trying to do. Some sample code would probably help.

Comment: @Noam If you will apply update table_name set column_name = <value>...then it will update all the rows

Comment: Type the my_table values as you expect them to be AFTER the update took place, please

Comment: @Martin updated as you requested

Comment: and now find the solution, but I would not know better then MarcB did.

Answer (score 3):

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE col1='v1';
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) values ('v1', 'v10', 'v11');
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) values ('v1', 'v4', 'v5');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: +1 As it's tagged PHP too, these may be of use: [PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) or [mysqli::autocommit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php)

Comment: @Marc Will this be good performance wise? Is it better to calculate the diffs between the old data to the new manually in php and then doing only the relevant queries?

Comment: noam: it'd be far more reliable. Otherwise you have to select/fetch all the v1 rows (query #1), do a bunch of client-side calculations, delete unneeded rows (query #2), then run a bunch of individual updates, which may potentially fail if you've got any unique keys on the table involving these fields. This version has only n+1 queries (n being the number of rows you're wanting to change). Your version is n+2 + extra overhead for fetching the records in the first. And if you use MySQL's extended insert syntax, my version is a 1+1 situation for query count.

Comment: @Marc what is "MySQL's extended insert syntax"? n in your version is the numbers of rows I want to keep for col1=v1. In my version it is the number of rows which changed. I agree this is controversial, but still not convinced what's the best approach. I also wish to state that most of the rows remain the same and that's why I'm trying to avoid the delete (like the v4 v5 line). Also, why are you suggesting to do that in a transaction? what difference does that make?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html (search for `(1,2,3)`). The transaction guarantees that ALL the inserts must be completed without failure, otherwise all the original data will get restored. It's a safety thing.

Comment: @Noam: This is the best approach. Except off course if you usually have to DELETE 1000 rows and then INSERT 990 rows, identical to deleted ones and also INSERT 7 new ones. Then it might be more fast to DELETE only the 10 and INSERT the 7 new ones (faster mainly because of the less index updating involved). But still, the wise thing is to put the operations in a transaction.

Comment: @ypercube I usually DELETE 150 rows and insert ~140 which are identical (+~10 new lines). This is why it feels so weird to delete the whole 150..